# Sitecore database: get url for content tem from GUID

Tags: mysql, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8

I have the exported databases for a site that *was* on Sitecore.  What is the relationship needed to find the URL/path for a a content item?  For example, say I have article in Web db , items table, with GUID='x'.

Is the URL for that resource stored in another table? I was thinking maybe it is built from the Links table in the Core db, but I can't figure out the relationship. Thanks!

Comment: Do you only have the exported database or do you have Sitecore up and running locally? Sitecore stores the item hierarchy in a flat table structure, and you need to figure out the parent <> child relationship of an item in a tree structure. Even then, there are lots of other things at play. For that reason, you should only get the URL via the API to ensure it is accurate.

Comment: Thanks for you response!  Indeed, I only have the databases at this point.  I do not have access to the sitecore apis.  Most of the time I can accurately figure out the URL for a content item using the parent child relationship, as you suggested, however it does not always work.  I'm hoping I can figure out how the API builds the url since I don't have access to it.  Configuration values  aside, do you know how the API  builds the url's from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the URL, you should typically install a Sitecore instance with the correct configurations the site was running with and invoke the LinkManager API code with the GUID so you can determine what the URL was at the time the site was running.

Configurations affect the URL generation, as does the parent-child relationship mentioned by @jammykam.

URLs also are dependent on the language being viewed. For example, if you view a particular 'GUID' in english US, there may be an 'en-us' part in the URL. In french, the same 'GUID' may have 'fr-fr' in the URL. But, again, depending on configurations, it may not if it's a single-language site and is not enforcing language as part of the URL.

There are also some items, such as wildcards, which have a GUID but can have many URLs as they are intended to resolve a variety of possible URLs and then programmatically determine what to load.

In the end, I do not recommend using the GUID and the database to determine the URL.

Comment: Hi Jay - Thanks for your helpful response.  I don't have access to the API at this point, but I do have the databases.  I understand that the API uses configuration values to generate the url, nonetheless I'm looking for a way to build the relative path of each content item.  I have sussed out the parent/child relationship and I can translate that to the url _most_ of the time, but I'm seeing a lot of content that doesn't follow that convention.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Again, this comes down to configurations. For example, if the site was setup to use Display Names instead of item names for the URLs, then you would need to find the appropriate Display Name in the right language to resolve the URL.

Also, if there are any URL encoding configurations set up, this could affect how the item name is translated into a URL.

There is no real way to create the original URL based off the GUID in the database alone without taking into account the configurations and the logic in the APIs that build the links.